# quiz app - jquery issue with submit button in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

```
function submitAnswer() {
$('.textBox').on("click",".submitButton",function (event) {    

    event.preventDefault();    
    $('.js-responseBox').show();   
    let selected = $('input:checked');    
    let answer = selected.val();   
    let correct = `${store[questionNumber].correctAnswer}`;    
    if (answer === correct)    
    {    
      $('.js-responseBox').html(    
      `<h3>Your answer is correct!</h3>   
      <p>Good Job</p>    
      <button type="button" class="nextButton button">Next</button>`    
      );    
      updateScore();    
    }     
    else    
    {   
      $('.js-responseBox').html(    
      `<h3>That's a wrong answer</h3>   
      <p>Correct Answer is:</p>   
      <p>${store[questionNumber].correctAnswer}</p>
      <button type="button" class="nextButton button">Next</button>`
      );
    }

   });
  }

     function generateOptions(questionNumber) {      
     return `<section class="textBox">    
         <legend>${store[questionNumber].question}</legend><br />
          <fieldset>
             <form id="myForm">
             <br />  
             <label>     
                <input class="answer" type="radio" name="option" ></input>    
                <span>${store[questionNumber].answers[0]}</span>       
             </label>       
             <br />    
             <label>    
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="option"></input>    
            <span>${store[questionNumber].answers[1]}</span>    
          </label>    
          <br />    
          <label>    
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="option"></input>    
            <span>${store[questionNumber].answers[2]}</span>    
          </label>    
          <br />    
          <label>   
            <input class="answer" type="radio" name="option"></input>    
            <span>${store[questionNumber].answers[3]}</span>   
          </label>    
          <br />
```

I have tried many different ways

the submit button in the form is not working properly when clicked, it takes you to the previous page as if nothing happens

Comment: can you tell me when you call generateOptions this function ?

Comment: can you ask your question again please

Comment: at what point you are calling this function generateOptions()

Comment: function makeQuiz() {
  startQuiz();
  generateQuestion(); generateQuestion makes a call to generateOptions
  submitAnswer();
  nextQuestion();
  restartQuiz();
}

Comment: @Maryam, what am suggest "use strict" method and check your browser console these are error debug method...

Answer (score 0):

It could be that because the textBox object is created dynamically, the event handler for that element is not properly attached.

Try changing the selector to something that will be present on the page when the event handler is attached.

`$(document).on(".textBox click",".submitButton",function (event) {
  //function contents
});`

Here's a link to more info on this: https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

See the section titled "Delegated event handlers".

Comment: that was exactly the reason. I changes the .textBox to .js-questionBox in my html, now submit button is working for the 1st question but when i click next and answer the 2nd questions, it does the same things (goes back to start page)